# How to keep html from appending to a span; when the total of a count (of divs) is zero?

Tags: jquery

I am counting divs by *class*. The total amounts are added to *spans* and displayed in-between brackets.

e.g. When there are 5 divs with class '1995' the total amount will be displayed like

`<span>1995(5)</span>`.

I am using the following code to achieve this:

```
const years = Array.from(
  { length: 500 },
  (_, i) => 1500 + i
);
years.forEach((year) => {
  const totalYear = $(`.${year}`).length;
  years.forEach((year) => {
        const totalYear = $(`.${year}`).length;
        $(`#index_year > p:contains('${year}')`).html( year + "<span class='counter'> (" + totalYear + ")</span>");
    });
});
```

I am trying to hide the amounts when the total of the count is zero as I wish to see `<span>1995</span>` instead of `<span>1995(0)</span>`. Hence hide the (0).

One way to prevent displaying (0) would be by checking if `totalYear !== 0` before I add the HTML to the span.

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to correctly add this solution to the code I am using... Please help.

**Edit**

Thanks to the [answer by Jamie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55404655/11256647) I have managed to hide the amounts *when the amount is zero* by adding the following:

```
  if (totalYear > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check if totalYear has a value and then add the span based on the response.

```
const totalYear = $(`.${year}`).length;
var totalVal = '';


if (totalYear > 0) {
    totalVal = '<span class="counter">(' + totalYear + ')</span>';
}

$("#index_year > p:contains('${year}')").html(year + totalVal);
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem as now both the counters with, and without a value are not visible.. any idea why this might happen?

Comment: I feel perhaps adding `totalYear !== 0` should do the trick I simply don't know where to put it -_-" yikes.

Comment: In the end it turned out `if (totalYear > 0) {...}`was sufficient and did the trick!

Comment: Nice one, glad it worked. Can you mark answer complete for future users?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the IF block to add or not not span with total:

```
years.forEach((year) => {
  const totalYear = $(`.${year}`).length;
  years.forEach((year) => {
        const totalYear = $(`.${year}`).length;
        let total = (totalYear > 0)?  "<span class='counter'> (" + totalYear + ")</span>" : "";
        $(`#index_year > p:contains('${year}')`).html( year + total);
    });
});
```